# MySQL getting last results depending on date from linked tables

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have a problem with which I need your help.

I will explain on example scenario what's the problem.

There is 3 tables: A, B, C.
B and C have many-to-one relationship towards table A.
B and C tables have multiple entries for one entry in table A.
I need to have a query resulting with only one entry from B and C, but the entry must be selected so that the latest date entry from B and C is the one that is returned. I cannot rely on IDs from B and C because they are not ordered and do not guarantee that largest ID will be the right one. The date from entries in B and C is only valid criterion.

Here is an example with sample data:

```
Table A

tableaid | Some data ...
------------------
 1 |  ....
 2 |  ....
 3 |  ....
 4 |  ....
    ...


Table B

id | linkid |    date    | colb |  Some data ...
----------------------------------------------
 1 |    1   | 01/01/2000 |  A1  |     ....
 2 |    1   | 05/20/2001 |  A2  |     ....
 3 |    1   | 07/10/2002 |  A3  |     ....
 4 |    2   | 10/27/2000 |  B1  |     ....
 5 |    2   | 01/01/2001 |  B2  |     ....
 6 |    2   | 06/01/2002 |  B3  |     ....
 7 |    3   | 05/01/2000 |  C1  |     ....
 8 |    3   | 01/01/2003 |  C2  |     ....
 9 |    4   | 05/01/2004 |  D1  |     ....
         ...

Table C

id | linkid |    date    | colc |  Some data ...
----------------------------------------------
 1 |    1   | 01/01/2000 |  a1  |     ....
 3 |    1   | 05/20/2005 |  a2  |     ....
 2 |    2   | 07/10/2000 |  b1  |     ....
 4 |    2   | 10/27/2003 |  b2  |     ....
 8 |    2   | 01/01/2005 |  b3  |     ....
 6 |    3   | 06/01/2001 |  c1  |     ....
 9 |    3   | 05/01/2005 |  c2  |     ....
 5 |    4   | 01/01/2000 |  d1  |     ....
 7 |    4   | 05/01/2004 |  d2  |     ....
         ...

Result
=============================================
tableaid | colb | colc | Some other data ...
---------------------------------------------
 1       |  A3  |  a2  | ...
 2       |  B3  |  b3  | ...
 3       |  C2  |  c2  | ...
 4       |  D1  |  d2  | ...
    ...
```

I know how to do this with only A and B or C, but not with A and B,C. Any help appreciated. I have cookies :)

Comment: Dates adhere to a specific format in SQL. This isn't it!

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, agree. Composed it by hand and forgot about that... But still the point of the question could be deduced with or without proper SQL format notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subselect like

```
select a.*,
 (select colb from tableb b where b.linkid = a.tableaid order by b.date desc limit 1) as colb
from tablea a
```

similar stuff for colc.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much @ain That's what I've needed exactly!